# Angular - Directive reflecting ngModel array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is piggy-backing a little off an earlier question.  I have been trying to work with directives and data from a model/array

My model looks something like this:

```
$scope.testModel = {
    inputA:[1,2,3]
};
```

Then I would have inputs for each.

My directive is checking, on keyup, if the input is greater than a given number (10).  If it is, then it sets it as 10.

```
link: function(scope, element) {          
      scope.$watch('ngModel',function(val){
          element.val(scope.ngModel);
      });
      element.bind("keyup", function(event) {
          if(parseInt(element.val())>10){
              element.val(10);
              scope.ngModel=element.val();
              scope.$apply();
          }
      });          
  }
```

The problem is that I get an error, depending on the input:

TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Here is the fiddle to see the error and code I have set up: https://jsfiddle.net/prXm3/3/

**NOTE**

I would prefer not to change the data set as I receive it directly from the server.  I know I can change the model to `inputA0:1,inputA1:2,inputA2:3` and get it to work, but then I would have to transform the data when my app gets it, and then re-transform it when I send to back to the server.  I would prefer to leave the model as I have it set.

Comment: this very much looks like form validation, have you read the read the appropriate section in the [developer guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms). Look for **Custom Validation**.

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks for the tip, but ultimately I will be tweaking this to constrain input to specific ranges/formats.  Form validation will allow them to enter whatever, but then not allow them to submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your directive is interacting with `ngModel`, you should work along with it in order to update both the model and the view:

```
angular.module('test', []).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel',      
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {                              
          if (!ngModel) return;

          ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
              if(parseInt(viewValue) > 10) {
                  ngModel.$setViewValue(10);
                  ngModel.$render();        
                  return 10;
              }
              else
                  return viewValue;
          });          
      }
  }
});
```

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prXm3/5/).

Perhaps you'd be interested in checking out the following posts for further information:

- [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController)
- [Developer's Guide on Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: Genius.  I am going to have to read up on the NgModelController.  I spent way too much time stuck on this.