# Passing data from custom directive into parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created custom angular directive. For an example:

**Custom directive:**

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
app.directive('customDirective',function(){
return{
   restrict:A,
   controller:customDirectiveController,
   scope:{
         someArray:"="
         }
   }
})
```

**Custom directive controller:**

```
app.controller('customDirectiveController',function(scope){
    scope.someArray=[];
    scope.someArray.push(1);
    scope.someArray.push(2);
    scope.someArray.push(3);
});
```

**Parent controller:**

```
app.controller('parentCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.result=[];
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-ng-controller="parentCtrl">
  <div data-custom-directive="result">
</div>
```

How can I get value of this someArray from custom directive into Parent controller( result variable should in Parent controller be same as someArray from custom directive controller)?

Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mehmedju/RmDuw/302/
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a **'$watch'** on the array like this:

**In the controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.someArray = [];
})
```

**In the HTML:**

```
<div custom-directive arr="someArray">
</div>
```

**In the directive:**

```
app.directive('customDirective', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
           arr: '='
        }
    }
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('arr', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            //do your array manipulation here
        }
    }
})
```

### Alternatively, if you just want to send data back, here's the method:

**In the controller**, create a function which will accept the value returned from the directive, example:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function(){
    $scope.watchVal = function(val) {
        //do array manipulation
        $scope.apply(); //to update the scope
    }
})
```

**In the HTML:**

```
<div custom-directive data-method="watchVal">
</div>
```

**In the directive:**

```
app.directive('customDirective', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            sendVal: '&method'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
           scope.updateVal = function(){
               var func = scope.sendVal();
               func(scope.someArray);
           }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: well you can send the data back to the custom directive controller and from there you can use a service to pass around data between the controllers. Or maybe use $rootScope(not sure on this).

Answer (score 0):

Let's just say you are using tempController 
So your code should be

```
app.controller('tempController', function($scope) {
    scope.someArray = []
});
```

Html Code for this is

```
<div ng-controller="tempController">
   <div custom-directive some-array="someArray">
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work for some reason.When I try to read the value of someArray variable get empty array as result.

Comment: If you have used same code that you posted than there is problem in your customDirectiveController there is no such thing like "scope" in controller you should change it to "$scope"

Comment: That was my mistake in typing. Don't look at syntax mistakes

Answer (score 0):

You have here a very interesting article about watchers
http://teropa.info/blog/2014/01/26/the-three-watch-depths-of-angularjs.html

You need use a watchCollection

And, If you are playing creating the array and change the reference inside the directive you can lost the reference inside the watcher. This mean don't create o change the array reference inside.

Another interesting way is use ngModel
http://jsfiddle.net/ta66J/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.formVals = {
        dirVals: [
            {val: 'one'},
            {val: 'two'}
        ]
    };
}

app.directive('dir', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            var html = "<input id='inputId' type='text' ng-model='" + attrs.dirModel + "' />";
            element.replaceWith(html);
            return function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                $compile(angular.element(element))(scope);
            };
        },
    };
});
```

The jsfidler is from this interesting thread:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/QgcRBpjiHAQ

Comment: Is it possible there is no easier way to solve this.

Comment: Maybe, but if you are creating a new form element (maybe not) ngModel is the right way ;).

If not watchCollection But be careful you don't change the reference.

Comment: Btw, the best way to help to find a solution is to create a jsfiddle, we can modify and propose a solution.

Comment: I will insist in ngModel :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747573/angular-directive-reflecting-ngmodel-array
Inside you have a jsfiddle that do exactly that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed issue.

```
 <div custom-directive="" data-some-array="result"></div>    {{result}}
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/mehmedju/RmDuw/304/][1]

Comment: Link is broken.